# AngularJs error:Argument 'FormController' is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, forms

Ok I have like 2 angular apps. One is automatically and the other one is bootstrapped.

Now everything works mostly fine but in console I have this error:

> Error: Argument 'FormController' is not a function, got undefined
>       at Error (native)
>       at cb (
>   etc...

But the form works I have tested it, tho the error is still there. Now the thing that breaks it is that I want to place the form above the ng-view div but when I'm doing so then the ng-view div stops working.

When I deleted the ng-controller="FormController" from the form, then the ng-view div pages appear but form loses it's function obviously.

Maybe someone more experienced can spot the problem or offer a possible alternative.

Strip of the code.

```
<html ng-app="kaidoweb">
<head>
    <!-- add javascripts -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

  // creating Angular Module
  var websiteApp = angular.module('websiteApp', []);
  // create angular controller and pass in $scope and $http
  websiteApp.controller('FormController',function($scope, $http) {
  // creating a blank object to hold our form information.
  //$scope will allow this to pass between controller and view
  $scope.formData = {};
  // submission message doesn't show when page loads
  $scope.submission = false;
  // Updated code thanks to Yotam
  var param = function(data) {
        var returnString = '';
        for (d in data){
            if (data.hasOwnProperty(d))
               returnString += d + '=' + data[d] + '&';
        }
        // Remove last ampersand and return
        return returnString.slice( 0, returnString.length - 1 );
  };
  $scope.submitForm = function() {
    $http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : 'process.php',
    data : param($scope.formData), // pass in data as strings
    headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
  })
    .success(function(data) {
      if (!data.success) {
       // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
       $scope.errorName = data.errors.name;
       $scope.errorEmail = data.errors.email;
       $scope.errorTextarea = data.errors.message;
       $scope.submissionMessage = data.messageError;
       $scope.submission = true; //shows the error message
      } else {
      // if successful, bind success message to message
       $scope.submissionMessage = data.messageSuccess;
       $scope.formData = {}; // form fields are emptied with this line
       $scope.submission = true; //shows the success message
      }
     });
   };
});

 angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('websiteApp'), ['websiteApp']);
    });   
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="position:relative">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

    <div id="websiteApp" class="contactRow">

        <img class="close" src="img/close.png" ng-click="closeForm()" />
        <form ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="FormController" novalidate class="contactForm" name="form" ng-hide="loaded">
          <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="SINU NIMI" ng-model="formData.name" ng-class="{'error' : errorName}">
          <input class="input2" type="email" name="email"  placeholder="SINU E-MAIL" ng-model="formData.email" ng-class="{'error' : errorEmail}">
          <div ng-class="{'submissionMessage' : submission}" ng-bind="submissionMessage"></div>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT!
extra code as demanded! app.js

```
    'use strict';

// angular.js main app initialization
var app = angular.module('kaidoweb', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
        when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'pages/index.html',
         activetab: 'index',
         controller: HomeCtrl 
       }).
        when('/works', {
          templateUrl: 'pages/works.html',
          controller: PrivacyCtrl,
          activetab: 'works'
        }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]).run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$browser', '$timeout', "$route", function ($scope, $http, $browser, $timeout, $route) {

        $scope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (scope, next, current) {
          $scope.part = $route.current.activetab;
        });

  }]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
    $location.hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

And controller.js

```
    'use strict';

// optional controllers
function HomeCtrl($scope, $http) {
}

function ProjectCtrl($scope, $http) {
}

function PrivacyCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout) {
}

function AboutCtrl($scope, $http, $timeout) {
}
```

Comment: I suggest using a different name. Angular already has a FormController https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController

Comment: `ng-app="kaidoweb"` in index.html but `angular.module('websiteApp')` .. is this the issue?

Comment: @HankScorpio just changing the FormController to another name  doesnt't seem to have an effect.
Shehryar ng-app="kaidoweb" comes from the app.js file already.

Comment: That wasn't a suggestion to fix the issue (otherwise I'd have posted it as an answer). I was letting you know about that so you could avoid ambiguous naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a second angular app for the form? 
Wouldn't it be better to put the FormController inside your "kaidoweb"-App?

```
var app = angular.module('kaidoweb', []);
//your code goes here

app.config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
    $location.hashPrefix('!');
}]);

app.controller('FormCrl', ['$scope', '...' function($scope, ...){
    // FormController code goes here
}]);
```

Then in your HTML

```
<body>

<div style="position:relative">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>

<div class="contactRow" ng-controller="FormCtrl">

    <img class="close" src="img/close.png" ng-click="closeForm()" />
    <form ng-submit="submitForm()" ng-controller="FormController" novalidate class="contactForm" name="form" ng-hide="loaded">
      <input class="input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="SINU NIMI" ng-model="formData.name" ng-class="{'error' : errorName}">
      <input class="input2" type="email" name="email"  placeholder="SINU E-MAIL" ng-model="formData.email" ng-class="{'error' : errorEmail}">
      <div ng-class="{'submissionMessage' : submission}" ng-bind="submissionMessage"></div>
    </form>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: About  the app.controller('FormCrl') What am I suppose to write in the two of '...' spaces. Also  must I edit the FormController code in anyway, aside from docoument ready which I assume if doing things like you suggested is not necessary. It didnt work and gives an error beginning of the app.controller(FormCrl')... line . Sorry if you can be bit more specific, I'm no expert on the matter.

Comment: For the '...' You can add any provider you want like $rootScope or $http and so on. In your case replace the dots with $http. You don't have to change your code of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the extra code, I believe you need to declare your controller on your app like this:

```
 app.controller('yourCtrl'.....
```